# event placed inside function parameter

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm learning javascript right now and am going through events. One thing that kind of left me stumped is why "event" is placed as the parameter within the function. To be more specific, I attached a sample of the code. Does "event" in this palce refer back to the "click" event listener, and if it does, what's the purpose or how do they relate to each other?

I'm still a bit of a beginner, so a pretty simple explanation would be great

`submitEl.addEventListener("click", function(event) { console.log(event); }`

Comment: It is the actual event instance.  `'click'` is not an event.  It's just a string, that tells `addEventListener` what events to handle for.

Comment: @Taplar got it. So without adding the event as the parameter, the function doesn't know to refer to the actual event, and the "click" string is telling the listener what event to specifically listen for?

Comment: That's the gist of it.

Answer (score 1):

addEventListener is simply a method/function that takes two parameters, a string and a function.

e.g:

```
function addEventListener(eventIndicator /*string eg 'click' etc*/, callbackFunction) {
    switch(eventIndicator) {
        case 'click':
            callbackFunction(/* event object */) // addEventListener calls the function you provide as an argument and passes an event object to the function
            break
        // etc...
    }
}
```

EDIT:
P.S this is just a simple explanation on how callback functions work, and where `event` comes from.